# Change specific List view item background color after getting some stored value from other activity

Tags: android, listview, background-color, listviewitem

> My Question: Change specific List view item background color after
>   getting some stored value from other activity.

**Details:**

I have a custom List view which has three text views and one small image.

First text view contains the name of the teacher, second contains cnic no and third contains personal no.

Now after getting few records, these records are saved in my list view. Lets suppose I get three teacher records and my List view now displaying three different list items.

**What i'm trying to do:**

Now what i am doing is that whenever i click on any list view item it shows me new activity named 'Mark Attendance' and in that activity there are three radio buttons, first is present, then absent then transfer out. Now what i want is that when i tap on any of these radiobuttons then the specific radio button value should be stored and activity should pass this stored value to my previous activity and the color of that list item should change.

i.e if I selected 'present' in Mark Attendance activity then the present value should be stored and the list item color that was clicked changes its background color to White or Green.

This is what I am doing but nothing happened after storing value.

This is the MarkAttendance class and when save button clicked then the radio button values should be stored.

**My Code:**

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.one)
            {
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MarkAttendance.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("datapresent", "present");
                editor.commit();
                Log.e("value", "datapresent");
                finish();
            }
            else if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.two)
            {
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MarkAttendance.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("dataabsent", "absent");
                editor.commit();
                Log.e("value", "dataabssent");
                finish();
            }
            else if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.three )
            {
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MarkAttendance.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("datatransfer", "transferout");
                editor.commit();
                Log.e("value", "datatransfer");
                finish();
            }
```

and this is what I am doing in my previous activity OnResume method

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(TeacherPresence.this);
    String present = prefs.getString("datapresent", "");
    String absent = prefs.getString("dataabsent", "");
    String transfer = prefs.getString("datatransfer", "");
                                /*String present = getIntent().getExtras().getString("datapresent");
                                String absent = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataabsent");
                                String transfer = getIntent().getExtras().getString("datatransfer");*/
    if (present.equals("present")) {
        listcontent.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    else if (absent.equals("absent")) {
        listcontent.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if (transfer.equals("transferout")) {
        listcontent.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
```

But nothing happened when i get back to this activity from MarkAttendance activity.

Where I did I do something wrong?

Comment: You can check that special value in Adaptor of list view and from adaptor you can make changes what you want. Try this once.

Comment: onResume isn't always guaranteed to work. Try [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for communication between your components (Publish-Subscribe architecture).

Comment: @KailasBhakade Can you please guide us more?

Comment: @KunalChawla  Now the value is showing in LOG file with same procedure that i write but list view color not changes when i get back to this activity

Comment: @ArslanAli Please paste the entire class code (both classes and xml) so that I can try it on my system and help you better.